# IEDriverServer is not found even when it is in the path on jenkins slave

Tags: internet-explorer, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I've been trying to set up my jenkins slave to run our automated tests with IE. I've downloaded the **IEDriverServer.exe** and added its path to **PATH** environment variable. Below is my current path:

**`C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;`**

But when I ran my jenkins job, it gave me an error of

**`WebDriverException: Message: 'IEDriverServer.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver`**

I've tried removing the .exe part of the path but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on what is causing this problem? It would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, i hope you would have already done it if not do it. After downloading did you unzip and place the `IEDriverServer.exe` in  `C:\IEDriver\` folder

Comment: Hi siva, I've done it. I already extracted the file and put it in my folder which is **C:\IEDriver\**

Comment: Okay. How about just adding  `C:\IEDriver`

Comment: I've also done that as indicated in the question

Comment: Well I tried it making it to **C:\IEDriver\** and it worked. weird. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do 2 things:**

1. In the PATH, you need to add the path to the folder of the executable
   instead of:
   C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;
   should be:
   C:\IEDriver;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;
2. Restart jenkins. it reads the environment variables once on startup.